# Drawing two straight lines with different slopes

Tags: diagrams, line

I wanna to draw a simple figure (attached figure) of two lines with different slopes on which two simple equation is[image] written.

any suggestion?

thanks

Comment: You can search about `tikz` or `pgfplots`. Their very first examples are enough.. and this way you could add a MWE if you find any problem

Comment: Try `\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[cyan] (0,3) -- ++ (40:3) node[midway,below,sloped,black]{$a_1+a_2(\varphi)$}
 -- ++ (10:4) node[near end,above,sloped,black]{$a_3+a_4(\varphi)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`.

Comment: @marmot are you making this up as you go or did you actually compile it and then copy the code into a comment?

Comment: @thymaro Marmots don't go, we crawl. ;-) (I think I have checked one, or are you saying it doesn't work?)

Comment: I knew it. You're just looking at OP's image typing code into the comment box as you crawl along and hope it works, which it does. I don't know whether I should be amazed by this or just not.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version drawn in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) - a language for drawing that's embedded in Context and LuaLatex with the `luamplib` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    % define some points
    z0 = (0, 30);
    z1 = (50, 80); 
    z2 = (140, 100);

    % and three paths
    path xx, yy, ff;
    ff = z0 -- z1 -- z2;
    xx = origin -- (x2, 0);
    yy = xx rotated 90;

    % draw the paths + the dashed line
    draw (x1, 0) -- z1 dashed evenly;
    draw ff withcolor 3/4 green;
    draw xx withcolor 2/3 blue;
    draw yy withcolor 2/3 blue;

    % some regular labels
    label.top("$\alpha, \phi_c$", point 1 of yy);
    label.bot("$a_5$", (x1, 0));
    label.bot("$\phi_e$", 1/2(x1+x2, 0));

    % rotated labels are a little more complicated
    label(textext("$a_1 + a_2(\phi)$") rotated angle direction 1/2 of ff, 
                   point 1/2 of ff shifted (7 up rotated angle direction 1/2 of ff));
    label(textext("$a_3 + a_4(\phi)$") rotated angle direction 3/2 of ff, 
                   point 3/2 of ff shifted (7 up rotated angle direction 3/2 of ff));


endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```